# Spring IoC container - Define dependency on classes annotated with a specific annotation?

Tags: spring

I have a bean which scans for classes annotated with a particular annotation (a domain specific one). I want to ensure that all the beans annotated with `@MyDomainAnnotation` are initialised and instantiated before the bean which scans for beans annotated with `@MyDomainAnnotation`.

Is there a way to define such a dependency as this is part of a framework and therefore new classes might be "plugged in". Basically I don't know the classes' names beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) on your scanning bean.

```
public class MyScanningBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  private boolean scanned = false;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    /* Published when the ApplicationContext is initialized or refreshed,
     * for example, using the refresh() method on the
     * ConfigurableApplicationContext interface. "Initialized" here means
     * that all beans are loaded, post-processor beans are  detected and
     * activated, singletons are pre-instantiated, and the
     * ApplicationContext  object is ready for use. */

    if (!scanned) {
      // scan for beans
      scanned = true;
    }
  }
}
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events

Comment: Take into account that the `ContextRefreshedEvent` can be triggered multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've added a check.

Answer (score 0):

Although I opted for implementing ApplicationListener as @Tichodroma suggested I also found another solution which sometimes might be what you want if you need some more fine-grained control over the order of beans' initialisation. So implementing [SmartLifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) you can provide phase values which will determine the sequence (in ascending order) in which your beans are instantiated (i.e. beans having smallest phase values will be initialised first).

But anyway I think the above answer is more elegant and clean in my case.